# Java classes modifiers

Tags: java

I am preparing for OCA exam. I have read that a class can be public, protected or private. I have also read that private and protected classes can be just inner classes (as a class defined in another one). I have seen that I can declare a class with no access modifier, which can be an inner class (as the protected and the private ones) and also a class in a .java file (as a public class).
My question is: Do these two classes have a default/package-protected modifier, or what are their modifiers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: Consult the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Now I see: I cannot import classes if they are not public in other packages or protected or default in the same package, or if they are private.

Answer (score 2):

A.S gives access privileges to outside of application

```
                         Private    Public  Protected   No modifier
Same class                     Yes      Yes   Yes            Yes
Same package Subclass           No      Yes   Yes            Yes
Same package non-subclass       No      Yes   Yes            Yes
Different package subclass      No      Yes   Yes             No
Different package non-subclass  No      Yes    No             No
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modifiers** --- **SameClass** ---**Package**---**Subclass**(same pkg)--- **Subclass**(diff pkg) --**Anywhere)**

---

public ---------->     yes --------->     yes----------->      yes ------------------------>       yes --------------------->       yes

protected ------>     yes-------->      yes ----------->     yes ------------------------>       yes --------------------->       No

no modifier
(default)  ------->     yes-------->      yes ----------->     yes------------------------->        No ---------------------->        No

private---------->        yes ------->     No------------>       No--------------------------->         No    ---------------------->     No

yes -> accessible
No -> not accessible